# How do I delete only a landscape specific xml layout file?

Tags: android, android-studio

How do I delete a landscape specific layout file?

In the image below if I press delete or right click and go delete it removes both the landscape and the default xml.
I realize I can remove it from the filesystem through windows explorer, but there has to be a way to this through the IDE (Android studio).

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Change the project explorer from the Android layout to the Project layout.

Open up `res/layout-land`, then delete the file from there.

Could also do it from the terminal / OS file-explorer

Comment: So from the android view it isn't possible to remove the alternate layout? Thought I was missing a shortcut key or something. I admit I forgot about the project view.

Comment: Not sure. Personally, I use IntelliJ, which doesn't have an Android view.

Comment: I did this, and it still deleted all the other variations from the project view, so I has to open it externally in file explorer. I'm using Android Studio 2.3.2, not sure if its a feature, bug or temporary glitch.

Comment: Better to delete it from OS file explorer only as it again gives usage warnings in Android Studio. Its location is "app\src\main\res\layout"

Answer (score 9):

You can right click the .xml you want to delete then select "Show in Explorer" and then delete the file.

Comment: Best solution in year 2019

Answer (score 0):

On the picture you are in Android view mode.. Change your View to Project Mode. 
then you will see res/layout-land folder

Answer (score 0):

I think the safest way is to right-click on the XML, open it in file explorer, and delete it.

Again those using `navigation-fragment or nav-host` must clean and rebuild the project from the top menu bar `Build`.

Otherwise, it may crash your app whenever you switch to the landscape as it does to me. Of this silly mistake, I lost a few hours of time.